# Rospack find problems

Tags: ros, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am at the point that I may have to uninstall and reinstall ROS.  I had ROS working fine, but now I am having some problems.  When I try to run `rospack find roscpp` this is what I get:

```
leaf@leaf:~/catkin_ws$ rospack find cpp
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/CATKIN_IGNORE: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/CATKIN_IGNORE"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/rospack_nosubdirs: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/rospack_nosubdirs"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/manifest.xml: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/manifest.xml"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/CATKIN_IGNORE: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/CATKIN_IGNORE"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/rospack_nosubdirs: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/rospack_nosubdirs"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/manifest.xml: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules/manifest.xml"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules"
[rospack] Error: stack/package cpp not found
```

But I get this when I :

```
leaf@leaf:~$ roscd roscpp
leaf@leaf:/opt/ros/hydro/share/roscpp$
```

My path looks ok :

```
leaf@leaf:~$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/leaf/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218219/rospack-find-problems/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-25**:\

> [..] but now I am having some problems [..]

In addition to what @ahendrix asked, could you perhaps also think about what you changed (recently)? Did you install any additional packages? Did you do anything with `cmake_modules` you shouldn't have? Etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-25**:
Also: you write you want to `rospack find roscpp`, but the error output you copy/pasted shows you ran `rospack find cpp` (note the missing `ros` prefix on `cpp`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the permission on `/opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules` is wrong.

Try doing an `ls -l` on that directory and **edit your question** to include the results:

```
ls -l /opt/ros/hydro/share/cmake_modules
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-25**:
That was the problem.  Some reason cmake_modules folder was gone on this machine, so I copied and pasted cmake_modules folder from another machine. But I didn't change permission to allow use of folders with the properties.  After correcting permission everything seems to work fine.  Thank you!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-25**:
You should never directly modify the contents of /opt/ros; if cmake_modules was missing, you should have reinstalled it through the package manager. You probably still should. On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-hydro-cmake-modules`

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-26**:
Thanks again!